# How to reference field in a JOIN within a JOIN?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

When selecting a specific field within a subquery in a JOIN statement, you use dot notation to reference the table.field_name, however, what to do when using yet another subquery JOIN within that first JOIN?

My example of the JOIN w/in JOIN:

```
JOIN (SELECT 
BUDGET.protocol_id, BUDGET.completed_date,
CONTRACT.completed_date,
REQUEST.completed_date,
RECEIVE.completed_date,
PC.completed_date,
FC.completed_date,
MGR.completed_date

FROM (SELECT completed_date, task_list_id, protocol_id FROM task WHERE task_name LIKE 'Budget%') BUDGET 

JOIN (SELECT completed_date, task_list_id, protocol_id FROM task WHERE task_name LIKE 'Contract%') CONTRACT 
    ON BUDGET.protocol_id = CONTRACT.protocol_id
    AND BUDGET.task_list_id = CONTRACT.task_list_id

JOIN (SELECT completed_date, task_list_id, protocol_id FROM task WHERE task_name LIKE 'Request%') REQUEST 
    ON BUDGET.protocol_id = REQUEST.protocol_id
    AND BUDGET.task_list_id = REQUEST.task_list_id

JOIN (SELECT completed_date, task_list_id, protocol_id FROM task WHERE task_name LIKE 'Protocol%') PC 
    ON BUDGET.protocol_id = PC.protocol_id
    AND BUDGET.task_list_id = PC.task_list_id

JOIN (SELECT completed_date, task_list_id, protocol_id FROM task WHERE task_name LIKE 'Financials%') FC 
    ON BUDGET.protocol_id = FC.protocol_id
    AND BUDGET.task_list_id = FC.task_list_id

JOIN (SELECT completed_date, task_list_id, protocol_id FROM task WHERE task_name LIKE 'Manager%') MGR 
    ON BUDGET.protocol_id = MGR.protocol_id
    AND BUDGET.task_list_id = MGR.task_list_id  

JOIN (SELECT completed_date, task_list_id, protocol_id FROM task WHERE task_name LIKE 'Receive%') RECEIVE
    ON BUDGET.protocol_id = RECEIVE.protocol_id
    AND BUDGET.task_list_id = RECEIVE.task_list_id
) TASK ON PCL.protocol_id = TASK.BUDGET.protocol_id
```

What I've been trying to do with the subqueries is select the specific task completed dates, so in the SELECT statement my instinct is to use TASK.BUDGET.completed_date, for each task. Yet, I get an ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined, so there seems to be something wrong with everything using completed_date

Comment: If you run all of the code you posted (minus the `JOIN (` that begins it), does it run?  It looks fine to me, so my guess is your error is on the outer select or grouping.

Comment: The subquery its self definitely runs, albeit slowly. The issue comes when in the main query SELECT statement I add in:  
    'TASK.BUDGET.completed_date,
    TASK.CONTRACT.completed_date,
    TASK.REQUEST.completed_date,
    TASK.RECEIVE.completed_date,
    TASK.PC.completed_date, 
    TASK.FC.completed_date,
    TASK.MGR.completed_date'

which throws the 00918 error

Comment: ) TASK ON PCL.protocol_id = TASK.BUDGET.protocol_id    -- where is the open bracket that goes to that?   Each subquery is best thought of as it's own table...everything in it is self contained and can't reference any object outside of it.   task.budget.completed_date will never be correct referencing.  Edit: this works if you don't have that task reference, no?   You are going to want to alias the columns in each subquery to avoid confusion (SELECT completed_date as budget_completed_date) or something like that

Comment: The correct alias should just be `TASK.completed_date`... The inner alias of `BUDGET` will not pass to the outer query.  Only the subquery/derived table alias will (`TASK`).

Comment: Similarly, give each of the `completed_date` columns their own alias.  ie.. `CONTRACT.completed_date AS ContractCompletedDate` then select them from that column name in the outer query.  ie.. `TASK.ContractCompletedDate`

Comment: The open bracket is from the intial `join (` statement. I see what you're saying. So each of the JOIN statements from within the subquery should just be added to the Main query?

Comment: You can keep it as you have it, but you can't pass a double alias `TASK.BUDGET.Completed_Date` up 2 levels.  It will just be `TASK.Completed_Date`.  Since you have multiple `Completed_Date` columns, you need to alias them in the inner select to make them unique.  Side note, see Gordon's answer, conditional aggregation will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @Dan - not quite.  Your issue is as much to do with aliasing as anything else.  They way it's currently written, task.completed_date is referring to 6 or 7 different fields.   Answer up, just alias better.

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: @AaronDietz aliasing is definitely the underlying issue. Just cleaned it up a bit and now i'm accessing what I want. Thank you!

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for the clarification - still new to the terminology

Comment: @Twelfth like I said to aaron, you got it right with the aliasing issue. Nice!

Comment: @Dan - if it's right mark the answer as such.   Honestly, you should be doing the aliasing at the bottom query level (in each join when you first introduce it), but thats simply readability for future people looking at your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.protocol_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN task_name LIKE 'Budget%' THEN completed_date END) as budget_completed_date,
         . . . 
FROM task t
GROUP BY protocol_id;
```

I'm not quite sure how `task_list_id` fits in.  You might also want to be aggregating by that.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff . I'm new to this so I'm unfamiliar with conditional aggregation. Do you have any references I could learn more from?

I think I'm going to go with the Aliasing quick fix even if it's slower and then learn more about conditional aggregation to optimize

Comment: @Dan . . . This seems like a major simplification of your code, one aggregation query rather than lots and lots of joins.

Comment: You're right, this worked much better when placed into the larger query. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Took a bit to understand, but I think I got ya.

```
SELECT 
BUDGET.protocol_id, 
BUDGET.completed_date,
CONTRACT.completed_date,
REQUEST.completed_date,
RECEIVE.completed_date,
PC.completed_date,
FC.completed_date,
MGR.completed_date
...
)task
```

So the 'budget.completed_date' can now be referred to as 'task.completed_date'.  And so can pc.completed_date and so can mgr.completed_date etc.  That's its confusion.  Just alias:

```
SELECT 
BUDGET.protocol_id  as budget_protocol_id
BUDGET.completed_date as budget_completed_date,
    SELECT 
BUDGET.protocol_id, BUDGET.completed_date,
CONTRACT.completed_date as contract_completed_date,
REQUEST.completed_date as request_completed_date,
RECEIVE.completed_date as receive_completed_date,
etc
...
)task
```

This will keep each task.complete_date unique and you can refer to them from there as task.budget_completed_date.  Make sense?

Comment: You got it. Aliasing was the issue. Still a very slow operation, but I'll work on optimization later. Thank you

Comment: Look to Gordon's answer for speed improvements...you are pretty much doing 7 full table scans here when it can be done much more efficiently.  What you are doing here can also be considered 'pivoting' or 'cross-tab', depending which database you are using there can be more efficient ways of working with it.

Answer (score 0):

If need to access columns of subquery in subquery then simply use them in `SELECT` of middle subquery:

```
 SELECT middle_subquery.c1
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT inner_subquery.c1
    FROM
    (
       SELECT count(*) c1 FROM tab
    ) inner_subquery
 ) middle_subquery
```

instead of

```
 SELECT middle_subquery.inner_subquery.c1
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
       SELECT count(*) c1 FROM tab
    ) inner_subquery
 ) middle_subquery
```